# Match id betwen URL and list React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm creating a blog with ReactJS. I have a data component that only contains my data for each articles. I'm able to show all my list of articles on my blog page. The problems comes when I click on an article. I'm able to get the ID in the URL and other params and show it in my article.

The problem: I'd like to not pass all the params into the URL...

I just want to pass ID into the URL, and say to my app:

Get all the values of the row that contain this ID from this data file.

Here the code I tried to fix it (it show a blank page):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import imgBien1 from '../../images/imgBien1.JPG'
import { ColumnSection, Section, SectionInterne, Column2, ContentWrapper2, Img, Column1,ContentWrapper, TopLine, Heading, Subtitle  } from './stockUnique'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import { posts } from '../Data/data'

const StockUnique = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const [blog, setBlog] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let blog = posts.find((blog) => blog.id === parseInt(id));
    if (blog) {
      setBlog(blog);
    }
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <Section >
      <ColumnSection>
        <SectionInterne>
          <Column2>
            <ContentWrapper2>
              <Img src={imgBien1} alt='ok' />
            </ContentWrapper2>
          </Column2>
          <Column1>
            <ContentWrapper>
              <TopLine>{id}</TopLine>
              <Heading>{blog.title}</Heading>
              <Subtitle>{blog.content}</Subtitle>
            </ContentWrapper>
          </Column1>
        </SectionInterne>
      </ColumnSection>
    </Section>
  )
}

export default StockUnique
```

My data list:

```
export const posts = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Hello World', content: 'Mon article 1', typeDeBien: "maison" },
  { id: 2, title: 'Bravo', content: 'Mon article2', typeDeBien: "terrain" },
  { id: 3, title: 'Charlie', content: 'Mon article 3', typeDeBien: "appartement" }
];
```

edit: Navigation code:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes  } from 'react-router-dom'
import React from 'react'
import StockPage from './pages/stock';
import UniqueStockPage from './pages/unique'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/stock" element={<StockPage/>} exact />
        <Route 
          path="/unique/:id" 
          // path="/unique/:id/:title/:content" 
          element={<UniqueStockPage/>} exact
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: are there any console error

Comment: No error, only a warning : 
src\components\StockUnique\index.js
  Line 18:8:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: do you have something like codesandbox?

Comment: I'm adding the code on codesandox

Comment: I've implmented the code on sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-hypatia-pqcgo9?file=/src/components/StockUnique/index.js

Now it shows an error than wasn't shared on Visual studio.

Comment: go on /stock in sandbox... and when we click on the button, we get this error : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'title')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given route:

```
<Route path="/unique/:id" element={<UniqueStockPage />} />
```

Then the `UniqueStockPage` has the `id` value it needs to search the `posts` array for the matching item.

There's no need for state here, just use the `posts` array and the `id` route path param to access the matching element and render directly. Don't forget to handle the case where no matching element is found.

Example:

```
const StockUnique = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const blog = posts.find((blog) => String(blog.id) === id);

  if (!blog) {
    return <div>No Blog Found</div>
  }
  
  return (
    <Section >
      <ColumnSection>
        <SectionInterne>
          <Column2>
            <ContentWrapper2>
              <Img src={imgBien1} alt='ok' />
            </ContentWrapper2>
          </Column2>
          <Column1>
            <ContentWrapper>
              <TopLine>{id}</TopLine>
              <Heading>{blog.title}</Heading>
              <Subtitle>{blog.content}</Subtitle>
            </ContentWrapper>
          </Column1>
        </SectionInterne>
      </ColumnSection>
    </Section>
  )
}
```

If you want to avoid searching the `posts` array each render cycle then use the `useMemo` hook to memoize the `blog` value.

Example:

```
const blog = useMemo(() => {
  return posts.find((blog) => String(blog.id) === id);
}, [id]);
```

[image: Edit match-id-betwen-url-and-list-react-js]

Answer (score 1):

You might have to check if id has a value

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(id){
    let blog = posts.find((blog) => blog.id === parseInt(id));
    if (blog) {
        setBlog(blog);
    }
 }
}, [id]);
```

Comment: This should be the solution since the useParams is probably slower that useEffect on initial rendering

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work, I still have a blank page

Comment: post the navigation code

Comment: I added the navigation code #edit

Comment: can you add a console log inside the useEffect and see if any value is printing

Comment: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'title')

Comment: update useState `useState({});`

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka the console.log(blog) return the row I want... I just have a problem for show this value on the page.